# angular directive ng-hide not functioning when scope variable is set inside a scope function

Tags: angularjs, ng-hide

I need to set a few navbar items to hidden based on user logged in using ng-hide directive. When I set the directive to a scope variable defined outside of a scope function it works. But when it is set inside a function it doesn't. Below is my code for your viewing. Can someone advice on how I can accomplish this.

//My controller code

```
ub.controller('signupController',['$scope','$log','$http','authFact',function($scope,$log,$http,authFact){
    console.log('we are inside signup controller');

    $scope.fblogin =function(){
    FB.login(function(response){

        if (response.status === 'connected') {
          // Logged into your app and Facebook.
          $scope.testAPI();
        } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
          // The person is logged into Facebook, but not your app.
          document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
            'into this app.';
        } else {
          // The person is not logged into Facebook, so we're not sure if
          // they are logged into this app or not.
          document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
            'into Facebook.';
        }
        $scope.fbresponse = response;
    });

    };

    $scope.testAPI =function() {
        FB.api('/me',{fields: 'first_name,last_name,gender,email,picture'}, function(response) {

            console.log('Successful login for: ' + response.first_name);
            console.log('email:' + (response.email));
            document.getElementById('status').innerHTML =
            'Thanks for logging in, ' + response.first_name + '!';
            document.getElementById('profpic').innerHTML =
            "<img src='" + response.picture.data.url + "'>";
        });
        $scope.accesstoken = FB.getAuthResponse().accessToken;

       //does not work when defined here
        $scope.test=true;
         };

    $scope.test=true;//works when its defined here

}]);

//My view
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar" ng-controller="signupController">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">                 

                    <li ng-hide="test">
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#/signup">Register/Login</a>
                    </li>
                     </ul>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

When a $scope variable is defined inside a function, then it is attached to $scope (or initialized) only when the function is called.

In your case the function is `$scope.testApi()`, which is called only when your response.status = connected from the facebook's response.

What you should do is first **initialize** the value of $scope.test = true or false outside the function and also **update** it's value inside your $scope.testApi() function. Like this:

```
// Initialize the variable test outside the function
$scope.test=true;

$scope.testAPI =function() {
    FB.api('/me',{fields: 'first_name,last_name,gender,email,picture'}, function(response) {

        console.log('Successful login for: ' + response.first_name);
        console.log('email:' + (response.email));
        document.getElementById('status').innerHTML =
        'Thanks for logging in, ' + response.first_name + '!';
        document.getElementById('profpic').innerHTML =
        "<img src='" + response.picture.data.url + "'>";
    });
    $scope.accesstoken = FB.getAuthResponse().accessToken;

   // Update the value
    $scope.test=true;
};
```

Comment: Tried it. It doesn't work. When console.log the test variable it does show "true", but the view does not receive it

Comment: How do you mean the view doesn't receive it? You are using ng-hide, so if the value of test is true your list element won't show.

Comment: I mean the view still shows the element & the attribute value shows as ng-hide="isAuth" and class is not assigned. I'd like to share a fiddle of my entire code, but I dont know how to initialize fb sdk through fiddle. let me know how else I can share my code. appreciate any help in this regard